# DNS configuration for domain trust

Tags: domain-name-system, trust-relationship

I am the DNS administrator for domain1.com.  We are setting up a trust with child.domain2.com.  This will allow us to resolve all resources in child.domain2.com.  There is also a resource in domain2.com that we need to resolve.  Will a query from domain1.com for computer.child.domain2.com be returned successfully, or will I need a separate forwarder to domain2.com?

DNS in domain1.com is Microsoft DNS.  DNS in child.domain2.com and domain2.com is BIND

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To resolve DNS names across both domains you'll need conditional forwarders from the Windows DNS servers to the BIND DNS server and vice versa. Establishing the Trust itself also usually requires conditional forwarders.